# Nhibernate group by - select latest row for each foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, group-by, queryover

I'm having difficulties with NHibernate and a simple GROUP BY expression.

I have a table with records of user activity. I need to return the latest activity row for each user, sorted by Time descending, which also corresponds to descending IDs (autoincrement).

Basically, this is the SQL I want to run:

```
SELECT * FROM log_user_activity GROUP BY UserID DESC
```

I searched SO for an similar question and got a bunch of answers with projections, subqueries, DTOs...

Is there any simple way this can be done, without defining a new DTO class, or using a projection with anonymous object where I have to manually specify all the columns again? A solution using QueryOver syntax would be preferable, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any simple way this can be done, without defining a new DTO class, or using a projection with anonymous object where I have to manually specify all the columns again?

No, there is no other way, then:

1. Select a **mapped object as is** or
2. Select a **projection** - *which could but does not have to be transformed into original or DTO object (we can always return `.List<object[]>()`...)*

But what we can do, is to profit from [16.8. Subqueries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-subqueries), and return just a list of mapped object as **they are**, filtered by these with the max `Time` property:

```
ActivityLog activity = null;

// subquery to be later used for EXISTS
var maxSubquery = QueryOver.Of<ActivityLog>()
    .SelectList(l => l
        .SelectGroup(item => item.UserID)
        .SelectMax(item => item.Time)
    )
    // WHERE Clause
    .Where(x => x.UserID == activity.UserID )
    // HAVING Clause
    .Where(Restrictions.EqProperty(
        Projections.Max<ActivityLog>(item => item.Time),
        Projections.Property(() => activity.Time)
    ));

// final query without any transformations/projections... but filtered
var result = session.QueryOver<ActivityLog>(() => activity)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereExists(maxSubquery)
    .List<ActivityLog>()
    ;
```

Also check these:

- [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)
- [custom result transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310) could be interesting for other cases