# NHibernate -How to conditionally load data from a column

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We are not using Fluent Nhibernate. We have a table with a blob column which we would like to load conditionally. We already have specified it as 'lazy' and lazy loading is working fine. Is there a way to not load data for that column **at all** on a certain condition ? (hence for the property in respective class)

For example, here is the mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Blah.blah.blah" assembly="Blah.blah">

  <class name="MyDocument" table="HEAVY_DOCS">
  <id name="Id" column="docnum" type="decimal"> </id>
  <property name="docname" column="docname" />
  <property name="details" column="details" />
  <property name="doc_data" column="document_data" lazy="true"  />

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and below is the code getting document

```
private IList<MyDocument> FetchDocuments(IList<string> docId, bool laodData)
{

if(!laodData)
{
    docs = (from doc in Session.Query<MyDocument>()
               where docId.Contains(doc.docnum)
               select doc).ToList();
}
else
{
 //if laodData is false dont load column document_data 

}
return docs ;
}
```

Comment: What is the condition? I don't really understand - if the data is lazy loading, then it won't load unless you need it. If you need it, why would you not load it? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @cbp added an example to illustrate better.

Comment: Your code is still quite confusing, but if your doc_data property is lazy loaded, and assuming lazy loading is working, it shouldn't be loaded anyway until you access the doc_data property.

Comment: @cbp as I mentioned in my question "Is there a way to not load data for that column at all on a certain condition ?" .. not load the data for the column at all is what our requirement is. There could be a **design** answer for this answer but I am looking specifically for technical possibility of solving it.

Comment: @lame_coder: Just don't access it at "certain condition" and it will not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way, how to drive column selection by our code, is to use `projections`. Adjusted code could look like this:

```
if(!laodData)
{
    docs = (from doc in Session.Query<MyDocument>()
               where docId.Contains(doc.docnum)
               select doc // complete object
           ).ToList();
}
else
{
    docs = (from doc in Session.Query<MyDocument>()
               where docId.Contains(doc.docnum)
               select new MyDocument            // in NHibernate world
               {                                // that would be called
                 docname= doc.docname,          // projection
                 details = doc.details,
                 // no "doc_data" for LARGE document
                 Id = doc.Id, 
               }
             ).ToList();

}
```

With [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections) the projections can profit from NHibernate built in powerful `Result Transformers`, which can fill even protected properties. Maybe see [this custom transformer example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310) for deep *(relations including)* transformations of `QueryOver` projections...

Comment: The limitation could be protected id column... but the concept should work... Enjoy NHibernate... awesome tool ;) PS: the QueryOver is better implemented in NHibenrate... so ... maybe try to at least check that ;)