# NHibernate QueryOver fill property object in parent object with projections

Tags: c#, nhibernate, properties, projection, queryover

I'm having a problem with my QueryOver and I don't understand why. My query returns the viewmodel object ContactInfo. I get this error on the Employee property: "could not find setter for property". How can I fill the Employee property within ContactInfo? What am I doing wrong?

**ViewModel Object:**

```
public class ContactInfo    
{
    public EmployeeInfo Employee { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string InternalTelephone { get; set; }
}
```

**Query**

```
public override ContactInfo Execute()
    {
        ContactInfo r = null;
        EmployeeInfo ei = null;

        var result = Session.QueryOver<Job>()
            .JoinAlias(j => j.EmployeeInfo, () => ei)
            .Where(j => j.EmployeeInfo.Id == _employeeId)
            .Select(
                Projections.Property<Job>(j => ei.Id).WithAlias(() => r.Employee.Id),
                Projections.Property<Job>(j => ei.FirstName).WithAlias(() => r.Employee.FirstName),
                Projections.Property<Job>(j => ei.LastName).WithAlias(() => r.Employee.LastName),
                Projections.Property<Job>(j => ei.ReferenceCode).WithAlias(() => r.Employee.ReferenceCode),
                Projections.Property<Job>(j => j.Telefoon).WithAlias(() => r.InternalTelephone)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ContactInfo>())
            .Take(1)
            .SingleOrDefault<ContactInfo>();

        var email = Session.QueryOver<Employee>()
            .Where(e => e.Id == _employeeId)
            .Select(e => e.Email)
            .SingleOrDefault<string>();

        result.Email = email;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26779306/1679310 or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26901453/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler I saw these solutions but your DeepTransformer class gives me a error at dictionary.Is() He does not recognize this function. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we can do is to use different than *default* result transformer, e.g. [DeepTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310).

In that case, the query must use **Alias** similar to the DTO model. So, if we have domain property `ei.FirstName` belonging to *JoinAlias* - `j.EmployeeInfo` - the alias must be reflecting the DTO ContactInfo - `"EmployeeInfo.FirstName"`

```
.Select(        
    Projections.Property<Job>(j => ei.FirstName)         // the mapped domain model
                          .As("EmployeeInfo.FirstName"), // the path in DTO/view model
    ...
)
.TransformUsing(DeepTransformern<ContactInfo>()) // the DTO
```

So now, the path *"EmployeeInfo.FirstName"* will be used to populate the `Employee` as a property *`EmployeeInfo`* and its property *FirstName*

And this Result transformer

- [DeepTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310)

DeepTransformer will use Alias to build up the reference tree. Could be used for references/`many-to-one` as well for `IDictionary` ... *(but not for collections)*

*NOTE: The `.Is()` method comes from some extensions, and can be replaced `with != null` like*

```
public static partial class Ext
{
    public static bool Is(this object value)
    {
        return value != null;
    }
....
```